# How to send POST/GET requests from Django Website to Spring Rest api?

Tags: python, django

I have a form in a submit.html file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


    {% block content %}
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Here you submit a new job</h1>

        <form class = "form" method="post">
            <label for="Company">Company Name:</label>
            <input type="text" value="{{ user.username }}" name="Company" id="Company">
            <br>
            <label for="position">Position:</label>
            <input type="text" name="position" placeholder="e.g Web Developer">
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>



    {% endblock %}
```

I also have another project built on Java Spring, and it provides the following api : 
http://myhost:port/projectname/api/addposition?compName=Google&category=Developer

where it actualy takes the username as the compName and the position input as category parameters.

I've searched for a way but I mostly found examples for inside requests, not to other api.

I'm trying to find a way to send a request to this api, using post method.This api can use either params via the url or data sent to it (like json for example) 
Sorry if question is not clear, it`s my first question on stack :)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you want to submit your form directly to the other website? and what does it return? and what are you supposed to see as a result?

Comment: @dirkgroten I want to send the company name and position from this form to the spring rest api as parameters. Then the spring project saves them to the database. I think it respond with ok 200.
As a result it would be great if it just said "Position Submited" (if that`s what you are asking)

Comment: Then you need to use javascript (ajax) to submit the form. But since your spring backend is saving the data to a database, it would probably expect a POST request. And there are a couple of issues here: you're making a request from another website, so if your spring API uses CSRF protection, you can't use it like this since it will not accept a POST request without a correct token. And you django backend would not know anything about this submission, not sure if you want that. And if your API returns an error, how does it return it? As json?

Comment: @dirkgroten this is just a college project, so I`ve "disabled" the csrf protection for the post api, so it can actually get the request. So I should go with javascript, right? There isn`t any other way that django provides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must submit the form for viewing and submit to an API.

For example:

submit.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


    {% block content %}
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Here you submit a new job</h1>

        <form class = "form" method="post" **action="api"**>
            <label for="Company">Company Name:</label>
            <input type="text" value="{{ user.username }}" name="Company" id="Company">
            <br>
            <label for="position">Position:</label>
            <input type="text" name="position" placeholder="e.g Web Developer">
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>



    {% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
import os
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

def api(request):
    Company = request.POST.get('Company')
    Position = request.POST.get('position')

    url = os.environ.get("URL", 'http://myhost:port/projectname/api/addposition?compName=Google&category=Developer')
    url = "%s" % (url)
    body = {"Company" : "%s" % Company, "Position" : "%s" % Position}
        response = requests.post(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('USER', 'PASSWORD'), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, json=body)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Code 200")
    else:
        print("Code not 200")
```

urls.py

```
from YOURAPP.views import api

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/',
         views.api, name='api'),
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed it worked, with some tweeks.